Does a bank have to confirm that I do NOT have a loan application in process?
After applying for a home equity line and not accepting a counter-offer, I would like a bank to send me an email like this:

We do not have a loan application currently in process for you. Sincerely, Name, NMLS#"

They are currently saying that they do not know whether they are allowed to tell me whether I have an application open.
Can anyone cite rules, regulations, or even common practice that would dictate whether they have to tell me this, cannot tell me this, or can choose at their discretion whether to tell me this?
The long story (if relevant) is that this bank made a low counter-offer because of a bad appraisal, so I applied at a different bank. The second bank has a tentative approval, but wants evidence that I am not still in process with the first bank. Second bank says an email to me as described above would be sufficient, and that the first bank should be able to tell me that I have no application in process (there is no disclosure to any third party, first bank just needs to tell me, the applicant, that I am no longer applying).
Of course I have the adverse action notice from the first bank, but it includes the counter-offer, and I need to show that I didn't proceed with the counter-offer. The information I've found in searching says that an adverse action notice was not required when I ignored the counter-offer. So the adverse action notice requirements are not helping me, I need to show that I have no application in process, rather than showing one version of the application was rejected.
Currently I am stuck between second bank insisting that the first bank should be able to do this, and the first bank saying this is a bizarre request they aren't sure is allowed.

This is in fact a bizarre request. I've been in a similar situation on multiple occasions, and have never encountered such a request. What the second bank have usually requested from me in this situation was a statement that I do not intend to complete the loan with the first bank. They have never asked for anything from the first bank, neither directly nor through me.
That said, one option I can suggest would be sending an email to your first bank representative stating "Hi, I'd like to withdraw my application submitted for the HELOC on property XXX", and ask them to respond with the confirmation of receipt.
If that wouldn't be enough for the second bank, then they are prpbably not serious about completing the transaction and are probably looking for a way to get you to withdraw.
